# Black listing synchronized keyword for groovy scripts

Tags: groovy

There is an application where users can provide custom groovy scripts. They can write their own functions in those scripts. I want to restrict people from using the 'synchronized' keyword as well as some other keywords in these scripts. For example it should not be possible to write a function like below.

```
public synchronized void test() {
}
```

I am creating a CompilerConfiguration and using the [SecureASTCustomizer](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/org/codehaus/groovy/control/customizers/SecureASTCustomizer.html). However adding org.codehaus.groovy.syntax.Types.KEYWORD_SYNCHRONIZED to the list of black listed tokens doesn't seem to do the job. (if I add org.codehaus.groovy.syntax.Types.PLUS it's preventing the usage of '+' within scripts.. but doesn't seem to do the job for synchronized)

Any ideas on how to achieve this ...

Comment: The [Groovy-user mailing list](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Mailing+Lists) is probably a better place for this question, as you're likely to reach the people who wrote the ASTCustomizer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
import org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilerConfiguration
import org.codehaus.groovy.syntax.SyntaxException
import org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassNode
import org.codehaus.groovy.control.SourceUnit
import org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.GeneratorContext

class SynchronizedRemover extends org.codehaus.groovy.control.customizers.CompilationCustomizer {
    SynchronizedRemover() {
        super(org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilePhase.CONVERSION)
    }

    void call(final SourceUnit source, final GeneratorContext context, final ClassNode classNode) {
        classNode.methods.each { mn ->
            if (mn.modifiers & 0x0020) { // 0x0020 is for synchronized
                source.addError(new SyntaxException("Synchronized is not allowed", mn.lineNumber, mn.columnNumber))
            }
        }
    }
}

def config = new CompilerConfiguration()
config.addCompilationCustomizers(new SynchronizedRemover())

def shell = new GroovyShell(config)
shell.evaluate '''
    class Foo { public synchronized void foo() { println 'bar' } }
'''
```

The idea is to create a compilation customizer that checks generated classes and for each method, add an error if the synchronized modifier is present. For synchronized block inside methods, you can probably use the `SecureASTCustomizer` with a custom statement checker.